# Under what conditions are these mixed model formulations equivalent?

Tags: random-effects-model, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model

I see models for "mixed effects" (i.e., models with fixed as well as random factors) specified in the literature in two ways, ***and I'd like to understand the conditions under which they are equivalent...***

**Model Formulation 1:**

$$ Y = \ X \beta + \ Zb +\epsilon $$
$$ \epsilon \thicksim N(0,\sigma^2 I) $$
$$ b \thicksim N(0,\Sigma)$$
$$ Cov(\epsilon,b)=0 $$
Here  the random effects are specified explicitly. The distribution for $ Y $, which can be written $Y \thicksim N(X \beta+\ Z b, \sigma^2 I)$, is sometimes called "conditional on $b$."

**Model Formulation 2:**

$$ Y \thicksim N(X \beta, \Gamma) $$
$$ \Gamma = Z \Sigma Z' + \sigma^2 I $$

Here, the random effects are specified implicitly via $Z$ and the elements of covariance matrix $ \Gamma $, the expression for which can be derived from the assumptions in  *Model 1*.  This formulation is like that used for "Generalized Least Squares."

These two different formulations are sometimes used interchangeably.  E.g., [Rencher and Schaalje, 2008](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/books/LinearModelsInStatistics.pdf). On page 480, the mixed model specification is like *Model 1*, whereas on page 486, expression (17.3), it is like *Model 2*.  In the latter case, it is being used for the exposition of residual maximum likelihood (REML).

My concern is, in using *Model 2* instead of *Model 1*, is one giving up some degrees of freedom in the calculations?  ***Or are these two formulations completely equivalent, i.e., both leading to the same results for $\Sigma$ and $\beta $ as a function of the observed data for $Y$, $X$, and $Z$?***

Comment: I think your understanding is correct, you are simply missing the intermediate conceptual step; please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

While I think your understanding is generally correct you appear to miss a small conceptual step. So let's say you have a fixed effects model with normal errors:

\begin{align}
y = X\beta + \epsilon \leftrightarrow y \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2 I)
\end{align}

where $X$ is your model matrix and $\beta$ your parameter vector. You generalise this model by assuming some random effects $\gamma$ associated with a model matrix $Z$. So you get something like what you labeled as Model formulation 1:

\begin{align}
y = X\beta + Z\gamma + \epsilon \leftrightarrow y|\gamma \sim N(X\beta+Z\gamma, \sigma^2 I)
\end{align}

Now assuming that $\gamma \sim N(0, \Sigma_\gamma)$ that means that Var($y$) = Var($Z\gamma$) + Var($\epsilon$) = $Z \Sigma_\gamma Z^T + \sigma^2 I$. As such the unconditional distribution of $y$ is what you labeled as Model formulation 2:

\begin{align}
y \sim N(X\beta, Z \Sigma_\gamma Z^T +\sigma^2 I)
\end{align}

So yes, these two model formulations are equivalent.

Comment: But does the choice of formulation constrain one's calculation methodologies and restrict availability of some info such as conditional modes of random factors?  I.e., see Bates' vignette for the R lme4 package, PLSvsGLS.pdf regarding computation.  Also, though you've shown Formulation 1 implies Formulation 2, does the reverse hold?  Many thanks for your interest and efforts!

Comment: The choice of formulation definitely affects ones methodology because it changes the problem's expression; `lmer` is great because it really transforms this LMER task to a sparse Cholesky decomposition. I think 'PLSvsGLS.pdf' is too sketchy, it always confused as a student; try Bates and DebRoyb 2004 'Linear mixed models and penalized least squares' first. If anything though the 'PLSvsGLS' (tries to) show(s) that both formulations can be expressed through a Cholesky factor (and thus yield the same solution). Yes the reverse holds you just "decompose" the variance instead of "concatenating" it.

Comment: @user11852, what is meant by 'decompose' vs. 'concatenate'?

Comment: Sorry for being cryptic, my bad; I was running out of space (and time). :) By 'decompose' I meant that you recognise that the variance Var($\epsilon$) has an association with a model matrix $Z$ so you break it into Var($Z\gamma$) + Var($\epsilon$). By *concatenation* I mean the opposite; you recognise that you variance components are are Gaussian and you add them up to get another 'concatenated' one. The book [Variance Components](http://www.amazon.com/Variance-Components-Shayle-R-Searle/dp/0470009594?tag=duckduckgo-ffab-20) - Chapt. 8 by Searle et al.  is great in explaining these issues.